# python calendar with holidays

Tags: python, calendar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Holiday Calendars, File Formats, et al.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986207/holiday-calendars-file-formats-et-al)

Hi,

Is there a calendar library in Python with which I can check for holidays, compute the number of business days from two dates (accounting for holidays in between)?

I'd love it if it is parameterized for the nation (e.g. US, Japan, etc) so that the holidays are counted for different countries differently.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of other StackOverflow questions whose answers may help you on your quest:

- [Holiday Calendars, File Formats, et al.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986207/holiday-calendars-file-formats-et-al)
- [Business days in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224742/business-days-in-python)