# Calendar package which accounts for different world regional calendars

Tags: python, calendar

Is there a calendar for python which also includes not just Gregorian but also calendars from other region such as Hindu, Chinese and Arabic? Since the market/national holidays of different world market are dependent on their regional calendars. Is there a calendar package which account for differing calendars?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look into [convertdate](https://pypi.org/project/convertdate/) which you can install with `pip install convertdate`. This package provides a bunch of calendars.

For the Chinese calendar, you might find this [LunarCalendar package](https://pypi.org/project/LunarCalendar/) helpful.

The answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682771/python-calendar-with-holidays) may also be helpful.

Comment: i was wondering if there is 1 package which has it all instead of converting dates or having to use multiple calanders