# Python date range generator over business days

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a generator function to iterate over business days (weekdays), skipping weekends (and holidays would be nice too!).  So far, I only have a function that simply iterates over days:

```
def daterange(startDate, endDate):
    for i in xrange(int((endDate - startDate).days)):
        yield startDate + timedelta(i)
```

I'm struggling to figure out a clean, efficient, and pythonic way to make the generator skip over weekends and holidays.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: See this question for the holidays: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986207/holiday-calendars-file-formats-et-al

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I would strong recommend using the [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) library for such tasks. A basic (*not* ignoring holidays) iterator over business days then simply is:

```
from dateutil.rrule import DAILY, rrule, MO, TU, WE, TH, FR

def daterange(start_date, end_date):
  return rrule(DAILY, dtstart=start_date, until=end_date, byweekday=(MO,TU,WE,TH,FR))
```

Comment: Does this actually do what you say?  I tried it on Python 2.7 and 3.3 on Linux and Mac OS, and in all cases it returns all days, including weekends.  If you look at `dateutil.rrule.WDAYMASK` you may see that it is a list of 0-6, i.e. all days, not only Monday-Friday.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Right, WDAYMASK is indeed incorrect (at least with current versions of dateutil). I updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: use `from dateutil.rrule import *` else you will get error as MO not identified

Comment: dateutil does not support iterating backwards, just in case you have a use case for this.  Apparently the author doesn't think this important. https://bugs.launchpad.net/dateutil/+bug/903925

Answer (score 12):

Assuming `startDate` and `endDate` are datetime or date objects, you can use [the `weekday` method](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.weekday) to get the day of the week, then skip it if it's Saturday or Sunday.  Just do:

```
def daterange(startDate, endDate):
    for i in xrange(int((endDate - startDate).days)):
        nextDate = startDate + timedelta(i)
        if nextDate.weekday() not in (5, 6):
            yield startDate + timedelta(i)
```

For holidays you will have to check manually for each holiday you want.  Some holidays are defined in complex ways so this could be a bit tricky.

Answer (score 11):

Python pandas has a built-in method bdate_range() with Business Days as it's default frequency. 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.bdate_range.html

```
import pandas as pd
pd.bdate_range(start='1/25/2020', end='2/24/2020')
```

Answer (score 7):

There's a useful library called `dateutil` that can do this sort of thing for you. It can generate ranges of dates (or dates based on custom rules), excluding certain days, consider a week starting on a day etc... Also has a somewhat more flexible timedelta than the builtin datetime library.

Docs at http://labix.org/python-dateutil/ - and available on PyPi

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_date_range(start, end, workdays=None, holidays=None, skip_non_workdays=True):
"""
This function calculates the durations between 2 dates skipping non workdays and holidays as specified
:rtype : tuple
:param start: date
:param end: date
:param workdays: string [Comma Separated Values, 0 - Monday through to 6 - Sunday e.g "0,1,2,3,4"]
:param holidays: list
:param skip_non_workdays: boolean
:return:
"""
from datetime import timedelta

duration = 0

# define workdays
if workdays is None:
    workdays = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
else:
    workdays = workdays.split(",")

# check if we need to skip non workdays
if skip_non_workdays is False:
    workdays = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

# validate dates
if end < start:
    return False, "End date is before start date"

# now its time for us to iterate
i = start
while i <= end:

    # first let's give benefit of the doubt
    incr = True

    # lets see if day is in the workday array if not then fault it's existence here
    try:
        workdays.index(i.weekday())
    except ValueError:
        incr = False

    # lets check if day is an holiday, charge guilty if so.
    # We are checking the index in holiday array
    try:
        holidays.index(i)
        incr = False
    except (ValueError, AttributeError):
        pass

    if incr:
        duration += 1
        print "This day passed the criterion %s" % i

    i += timedelta(1)

return True, duration
```